# Handling orientation change on Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-camera

I use the inbuilt camera application from my Activity to take a picture. The problem is that I am not able to handle the data returned from camera Intent if the orientation changes and my activity is redrawn, I tried to search for the same problem but it seems to confuse me more. Do I go for the bundle thing or I go for OnConfigurationChanged() I have placed the android:configChanges="orientation" in activity tags in Manifest file,for this particular activity which calls the camera intent, but the problem seems to persist. Can anyone please guide me to a solution.

Here is my Code:

```
if(i==0){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); 
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if( requestCode == 1337 && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if (extras != null){
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            // imgview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            image(thumbnail);

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(CreateProfile.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     
    }
}
```

Comment: whoah please do some code formatting before you post. Fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks a Ton mate will keep that in mind the next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this attribute to your `activity` in the `Manifest` file.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Thanks.

Comment: It was my first approach to tell that Android system, mate I am gonna handle this myself. But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

First of All, you have a problem in your code.

You ask if `if (extras != null){` but still get you bitmap from data `thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` This Line should be

```
thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Second, dont use android:configChanges, it messes up a lot of other things, and most apps shouldnt use it.

If you mean a orientation change after you have gotten the data, using saveInstanceState works good. try something like this, just put your data that you need inside the outState Bundle and get it back in the onRestoreInstance method

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
 outState.putAll(extras);
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 extras.putAll(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the target sdk of your app is bigger than 12 change it to 12 and try again pelase.

android:targetSdkVersion="12"

and also do not forget to add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" this to your activity line in the manifest

Comment: My Target SDK Version is 15 and minimum is 7 let me try this!

Comment: ok when it is 12 it will be work properly I guess, but you app will use sdk 12, so loading styles or check box styles of example will change